# std::unordered_map invalid read of size 8 in valgrind related to element erasure

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a wrapper around `std::unordered_map` to make it threadsafe (putting mutex lock and mutex unlock around all operations on the unordered_map.

Recently I was testing this wrapper class and i got an invalid read of size 8 from my wrapper's del function (which wraps the unorderd_map's erase(key) function). The delete returns a pointer to the value of the erased key-value pair. This is to be able to be able to free memory in case we're storing pointers to allocated memory in the unordered_map. For example if I store `string*` pointers (with allocated memory) in unordered map, del(key) would return a `string**` pointer.

However, when deleting the `string*` valgrind complains about an invalid read of size 8.

I wrote a small test program to reproduce the error:

compiled with `g++ -g -std=c++0x ./*.cpp`   (version g++ (Debian 4.9.1-16) 4.9.1)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

//wrapper class around unordered_map. 
template<typename KEY, typename VAL>
class Umwrap{
    public:
    Umwrap(){}
    ~Umwrap(){}

   //simple add. returns true when key is unique and add is succesful, false when key   isn't unique 
    bool add(KEY key, VAL val){
        auto respair = this->umw.emplace(key, val);
        return respair.second;
    }

    //delete key-value pair. Returns pointer to val.
    VAL* del(KEY key){
        VAL* retval = NULL;
        try{
            retval = &(this->umw.at(key));
        }catch(out_of_range &oor){
            return retval;
        }
        umw.erase(key);
        return retval;
    }

    private:
    unordered_map<KEY, VAL> umw;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    Umwrap<int, string*> testmap;

    testmap.add(1, new string("a"));

    //delete key-value pair. the unordered_map header says that it will not touch the memory pointed to by val, and that the user should do his/her own memory management.
    string** sta = testmap.del(1);

    delete *sta; //causes an invalid read of size 8 in valgrind.

    return 0;
 }
```

this gives me in valgrind:

```
==18625== 
==18625== Invalid read of size 8
==18625==    at 0x400D7A: main (main.cpp:46)
==18625==  Address 0x59ff1a0 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==18625==    at 0x4C2A360: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==18625==    by 0x402951: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<int const, std::string*>, false> >::deallocate(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<int const, std::string*>, false>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:110)
==18625==    by 0x4023F3: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<int const, std::string*>, false> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<int const, std::string*>, false> >&, std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<int const, std::string*>, false>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:383)
==18625==    by 0x401B55: std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<int const, std::string*>, false> > >::_M_deallocate_node(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<int const, std::string*>, false>*) (hashtable_policy.h:1977)
==18625==    by 0x4021C9: std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<int const, std::string*>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string*> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_M_erase(unsigned long, std::__detail::_Hash_node_base*, std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<int const, std::string*>, false>*) (hashtable.h:1796)
==18625==    by 0x4019C0: std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<int const, std::string*>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string*> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_M_erase(std::integral_constant<bool, true>, int const&) (hashtable.h:1823)
==18625==    by 0x4013E5: std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<int const, std::string*>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string*> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::erase(int const&) (hashtable.h:741)
==18625==    by 0x4011CA: std::unordered_map<int, std::string*, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string*> > >::erase(int const&) (unordered_map.h:500)
==18625==    by 0x400FFF: Umwrap<int, std::string*>::del(int) (main.cpp:28)
==18625==    by 0x400D71: main (main.cpp:44)
==18625== 
==18625== 
==18625== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18625==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18625==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 146 bytes allocated
==18625== 
==18625== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18625== 
==18625== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18625== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I'm somewhat stumped. A similar test program using `std::vector<string*>` in stead of `std::unordered_map<int, string*>` did not produce a similar invalid read error in valgrind.

So as a sanity check i'm asking here:
What am I doing wrong in/around the `del(KEY key){...}` function?
If not, is it a bug? Any pointers as to where to file a bug report would be helpful too.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're returning a pointer to a value which has been deleted from the map - you probably need to return a copy of the value ?

Comment: well, i'm returning a pointer to a pointer stored in the map. in /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:494 it explicitly states that unordered_map::erase(..) does not touch any allocated memory that unordered_map has pointers to, and that it's the programmers responsibility to delete this. but that causes the error i described

Comment: If `VAL` is a pointer type then the pointer itself (in the map) has now become invalid (but not whatever it points to of course). So you should just be returning a copy of the pointer.

Comment: @Geert Paul is absolutely correct. you're adding by-value, but returning by address. That simply isn't going to work. That the value you're adding is an address itself stored in a pointer doesn't change that. `del()` should return `VAL`, you should drop the `&` in the return calculation, and the caller should simply provide the same result type as the type inserted (in this case, a `std::string*`, not `std::string**`), which you're then responsible for `delete`-ing caller-side (a different issue, and ill-advised, but something you chose to manage so be it).

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig for your answer, if i understand correctly i'm pointing to a pointer (an int value describing a memory location) but the specific pointer i'm refering to does not exist anymore/went out of scope sometime during the delete/erase. Oddly enough this same kind of wrapper around a vector does not produce this error, that had me confused a bit.